# Merging CSV files on FTP site

Tags: excel, csv, ftp, merge

We have a power meter that sends a one record (headers and one row) CSV file to a FTP site every 7 minutes. In one day it creates about 5000 3MB files.

I am trying to think of the best way to show these files as one file/display in a spreadsheet or program.

I have been working on a quick access program that will import selected FTP files to the local machine, then they will be imported into a table where we can report off of them.

Is there an easier way?  Maybe just merge into an excel sheet locally thru macro?

Thank you for your help

Comment: If it uploads one file every 7 minutes, you should get 205 files per day, not 5000, surely? And each file has one record of 3MB? So, the line is 3 million characters long? I think Excel will have trouble with that...

Answer (score 1):

Perl can easily create an Excel spreadsheet from your bunch of files, and it can be put into `crontab` to do it automatically each night...

... but you'd need to provide more details of the file format, your environment and how you reduce your 15GB of data to something Excel can read.

Answer (score 0):

If you can SSH into the site, you could always run

```
cat *.csv > output.csv
```